# angular material bottom sheet do not bind data to content inside at seconds click?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular6

here is my server to test 
http://badpaybad.info/home-cook/

In localhost everything ok. In my server to test I got problem:
1st click bottomsheet render oki. 
2nd click bottomsheet do not bind data, API returned data oki. chrome no error logs.

here is code in ts file

```
          product = new ProductDetailHomePage();

      constructor(@Inject(MAT_BOTTOM_SHEET_DATA) public data: any,
        private homePageService: HomePageService,
        private bottomSheetRef: MatBottomSheetRef<ProductDetailBottomSheetComponent>) {
        this.productId = data.productId;
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.homePageService.getProductDetail(this.productId).subscribe(p => {
          this.product = p;
        });
      }
```

here is code in html file

```
        <button type="button" (click)="close()" mat-icon-button>
      <mat-icon class="material-icons" aria-label="hiden">arrow_drop_down</mat-icon>
    </button>
     {{product.Title}} <b>Code: {{product.ProductCode}}</b>
    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    <div class="product-detail-attribute">      <b>Gram: {{product.Gram}} </b> <i> Calorie: {{product.Calorie}} </i> Price: {{product.Price}}</div>
    <mat-grid-list cols="4" class="product-detail">  
      <mat-grid-tile class="product-detail-image" colspan="2" >
          <img src="{{product.ImageUrl}}" />
      </mat-grid-tile>
      <mat-grid-tile class="product-detail-description" colspan="2">
          <button type="button" mat-icon-button (click)="addToCart()">
              <mat-icon class="material-icons" aria-label="add to shopping cart">add_shopping_cart</mat-icon>Add to cart
            </button>
      </mat-grid-tile>
      <mat-grid-tile class="product-detail-description" colspan="4">
        <div  innerHTML="{{product.Description}}"></div>
      </mat-grid-tile>
    </mat-grid-list>
```

Comment: I am getting your bottom sheet every time, with what seems like the correct data because it changes depending on which item you click for. Can you try to explain more what the issue you are having is?

Comment: I try record my screen with CloudApp here is video link  
https :// cl.ly/1t3c25213j1R . localhost running well.

Comment: Ah, I see on your recording what you mean, but am not seeing it on my side still. I am using Chrome, what browser are you using?

Comment: I use Chrome and also try other browser, I have same problems. Anyway, Thank you very much for your help, It seem that only my computer got problem. I asked some friends, It also worked well. It is wired, I have no idea, but I can not use my computer to show demo any more :(

Comment: Okay no problem, I hope you figure it out!

Comment: I can simulate in localhost like this , it also won't bind data. Do you have any idea?  
      ngOnInit() {
          setTimeout(() => {
      
  
  
  
 this.homePageService.getProductDetail(this.data.productId).subscribe(p => {
        this.product = p;
      });
       }, 3000);
       }

Comment: I soleved by ChangeDetectorRef . constructor(@Inject(MAT_BOTTOM_SHEET_DATA) public data: any,
    private homePageService: HomePageService,
    private bottomSheetRef: MatBottomSheetRef<ProductDetailBottomSheetComponent>,
    public dialog: MatDialog, private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.homePageService.getProductDetail(this.data.productId).subscribe(p => {
      this.product = p;
      this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
    });
  }